# How to change payment checkout message in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I want to change the description message for Paypal for my shopping site. I want to put Japanese here and I tried to change several things.

[image]

This is the text what I want to change.
[image]

[image]
I changed that text in settings of woocommerce and paypal gateway plugin editor.  But not worked.

How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found really simple way. Sorry for posting such an idiot's idea but I want someone to save time and get a help through this even simple answer.

This needs no coding.
[image]

Go to Woocommerce->Settings->Payments->PayPal Checkout->Manage.

Then you can find description type form. Just put your text there. About other payments' gateway, you can do similar works.

Thanks.